# Elastic Search - How to perform IN condition in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

This is how my document looks like in elastic search

```
{
"entityId": "CAMP_ID",
"txnId": "TXN_ID",
"changeSummary": [{
    "field_name": "status_id",
    "old_val": "1",
    "new_val": "2"
}, {
    "field_name": "budget",
    "old_val": "100",
    "new_val": "250"
}]
}
```

I get a list of txnId and list of changeSummary.field_name and I have to get all matching documents. I initially tried this query:

```
{
 "query" : {
   "bool" : {
     "should" : [ {
    "terms" : {
      "transactionId" : [ "2915315c03b3420280eae04116fb303f" ]
    }
  }, {
    "terms" : {
      "transactionId" : [ "18faf80b3eb44e4b85be993a6d5fd40b" ]
    }
  } ]
}
},
"post_filter" : {
"bool" : {
  "must" : [ {
    "match" : {
      "changeSummary.fieldName" :  "abc" 
    }
    },{
    "match" : {
      "changeSummary.fieldName" :  "xyz" 
    }
  }]
}
}
}
```

This works fine but my problem is that list of transactionId can be really huge from 10 to 1000000 (or even more), and if size of list of transactionId is more than 1024 then I start getting

```
too_many_clauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024
```

Could someone please help in this?

Comment: The guys from Elastic [suggest](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/setting-index-query-bool-max-clause-count-in-elasticsearch-yml/27967) to **avoid** increasing the 'maxClauseCount'. Anyway, I guess it can be change under the yml config file.
You can read more [here](http://george-stathis.com/2013/10/18/setting-the-booleanquery-maxclausecount-in-elasticsearch/)

Comment: i also wanted to avoid increasing the maxClauseCount, so wanted to know if there is other way around

Comment: You don't have to branch out your query like that. You can do `"terms": ["id1", "id2", "id3"]`. The `maxClauseCount` limit is for the `bool` block. Also another way is if you do not have the necessity on a global query, you can run in batches.

Comment: @Varun Could you please provide an example or point me to any link? Thanks

Comment: Assuming you've not analyzed_fields, a sample would be: `{"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"terms": {"changeSummary.fieldName": ["abc","xyz"]}},{"terms": {"transactionId": ["2915315c03b3420280eae04116fb303f","18faf80b3eb44e4b85be993a6d5fd40b"]}}]}}}'`. Be aware of the caution quoted by @Eli wrt increasing `maxClauseCount`. If this doesn't work, your safer bet is to run in batches .

Comment: Thanks, will try this and let you know, meanwhile could you please point me to a link for batch query

Comment: @VarunNatraaj This is still giving toomanyclause exception

Comment: The I'd suggest to run your query in batches without passing all **N** `transactionID` and **M** `fieldName` at one shot.